# How to keep jQuery function from moving elements all the way to the left?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was able to implement the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5317900/1256700) ("position: fixed and absolute at the same time. HOW?") to get a div element to move with the rest of the page horizontally, but stay fixed vertically.  However, this solution causes the selected element to move ALL the way to the left of the page (with what appears to be a 20px margin).  I'm still new to javascript and jQuery, but as I understand it, the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var $this = $(this);
$('#homeheader').css('left', 20 - $this.scrollLeft());});
```

takes the selected element and, upon scrolling by the user, affects the CSS of the element so that its position from the left becomes some function of the current scrollbar position adjusted by the 20px margin.  If this is correct?  And if so, can anyone think of a way that I could change it so that instead of moving the selected element all the way to the left side of the window, we only move it as far left as my default CSS position for the body elements of the HTML document (shown below)?

```
body {font-size:100%;
width: 800px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;}
```

EDIT: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nxBg/2/show/) (code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6nxBg/2/)) that I made to illustrate the issue.  My page is designed so that when it is displayed in full-screen or near full-screen mode, the #homeheader element appears centered horizontally due to its width and the left and right margins being set to auto.  As the page gets smaller and smaller the margins do as well, until they disappear altogether and are replaced by the padding-left and padding-right settings of 20px.  So at this point (when the window is small enough that the margins disappear altogether), which is what the jsfiddle shows, the code appears to work as intended, but when the window is full-sized the JS overrides the CSS and pushes the div element all the way to the left (getting rid of the margin) upon any scrolling action.

Comment: What css is on `#homeheader`? Hard to say what's going on without an example. a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) might help :)

Comment: @ChristianVarga, I edited my post to include a jsfiddle but as you'll see from the rest of my edit, it doesn't exactly illustrate my problem...

Comment: Regarding your jsFiddle, simply add `/show` to the end of the Fiddle URL... [http://jsfiddle.net/6nxBg/show/](http://jsfiddle.net/6nxBg/show/)

Comment: @Sparky672, thanks for the tip!  I went back and changed the link in my edit above.  Hopefully this will help show what's going on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two events you need to handle to get this to work correctly. First is the scroll event which you are pretty close on. The only thing you might want to do is to use [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get the current left position value based on the document.

The other event which is not yet handled is the [resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event. If you don't handle this then once a left position is defined your element (header) will be there always regardless of whether or not the user resizes the window.

Basically something like this should work:

```
var headeroffset;
var header = $('#homeheader');

// handle scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // auto when not defined
    if (headeroffset === undefined) {
        // capture offset for current screen size
        headeroffset = header.offset();
    }
    // calculate offset
    var leftOffset = headeroffset.left - $(this).scrollLeft();
    // set left offset
    header.css('left', leftOffset);
});

// handle resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    // remove left setting
    // (this stops the element from being stuck after a resize event
    if (header.css('left') !== 'auto') {
        header.css('left', '');
        headeroffset = undefined;
    }
});
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/ELCq7/6/

http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/ELCq7/6/show

This type of effect can be done purely in css however, i would suggest taking a look at the full page app series Steve Sanderson did recently.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/

As an example you could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/ELCq7/18/

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  I haven't had much time yet to play with what you posted, but the idea of there being two events to handle totally makes sense.  However, when I open up your jsfiddle example, the div element no longer moves left and right when you scroll left and right (my intention is to keep it fixed vertically but not horizontally).  Was this intentional on your part?

Comment: interesting, for me in IE 10, IE7 and Chrome the header element moves as expected. My intention was to ensure that the header seems static when scrolling left/right, but fixed when scrolling up/down. If I had to guess it would probably be the `header.css('left') === 'auto'` that may be causing the issue you see. Perhaps the value returned is different and could be added to the condition.

Comment: Ah, you're right, it's a browser issue.  I'm running Ubuntu on a Mac so I've been using Firefox.  But I went over into OSX and tried your jsfiddle using Safari, and there it works as expected (although again, not using Firefox in OSX).  Is there a solution that would work for all browsers?

Comment: Alright, I have updated this slightly and can verify that it now works in firefox for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, Gary!  You're right, the solution appears to work in Firefox, although the horizontal position of the element sometimes seems to shift left when you resize the window and scroll left/right a few times.

Comment: Interestingly, I can't seem to get the JS script to work in my actual HTML file.  I can paste everything into jsfiddle from my HTML and CSS files, and when I put the JS you gave me into the JS window, it works fine.  But when I try to run everything from my dev server, something is breaking.  Do  I need to do anything besides paste the JS code you gave me between the '<script type="text/javascript"></script>' tags?

Comment: @GChorn Yeah, the example I provided does have some issues. As far as what you would need, the only thing that might be missing is a reference to jQuery. Something like `<script type="text\javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` prior to the custom script.

Comment: OK, so I can paste my entire HTML and CSS files into jsfiddle, and if I just remove the javascript from the HTML box and put it into the JS box, the script works, but if I have the script in both the HTML and JS boxes, even with the reference to jQuery as mentioned above, the script breaks and I get no left/right scrolling on the div element.  Is this just a feature of jsfiddle, that you can't include any JS in the HTML box or it will break/override any JS in the JS box?  Or could the JS in the HTML somehow be breaking the external JS script?

Comment: I guess I should mention that I have a second jQuery script running to make my tables sortable, and that including this script in the HTML section in my jsfiddle doesn't seem to affect the left/right div scroll script.

Comment: @GChorn that is my mistake, should be `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` (no type specified), updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/ELCq7/24/ . You may note from the updated fiddle that it no longer uses the jquery framework explicitly, but only the reference in the html section.

Comment: @GChorn another update in the most recent fiddle is that the jquery stuff is wrapped in `$(function(){...});`. This is just jquery shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`.

Comment: the change in the way jQuery is referenced seems to have fixed the issue.  Thanks so much for your help!  I'll need to figure out how to tweak the code to keep the div element from shifting to the right a bit (I'll be using it to keep a table header visible as you scroll down the page so the columns need to stay lined up), but this has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#homeheader').css('left', parseInt($('body').css('margin-left')) -   $this.scrollLeft());});
```

What I did here is just replace `20` with `body`'s `left-margin` value.

Comment: Ooh!  Thanks for your reply; I think this is heading in the right direction.  However, I think the "margin-left:auto" setting is somehow defaulting to a margin of 0, because now the element is moving even further left.  I then tried changing 'margin-left' from your answer to 'padding-left' but that just makes it go back to 20px from the left.